# if every continuous characteristic function is constant then ,M is connected

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness, characteristic-functions

prove for a metric space $M$, if every continuous characteristic function is constant then $M$ is connected.
I actually know how to prove the other direction, but I do not know how to work on this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M$ is not connected. Let $A$ be a connected component of $M$ and note that $A$ is open in $M$. Then $1_M$ is continuous but not constant.